# Installing OpenVPN on Red Hat 8

Tags: redhat, openvpn, epel

I am having an issue getting OpenVPN 2.4.8 installed and enabled on a Red Hat 8 server running as an EC2 instance on AWS.

The steps I have taken are as follows.

Added the EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) repository by running the following.

```sh
sudo dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
```

This installs the repository with no apparent issues, and I then install OpenVPN.

```sh
sudo dnf install openvpn
```

`dnf` finds the package and it appears to install it without any issues, as per the below output.

```sh
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                         1.5 MB/s | 4.0 MB     00:02    
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Thu Nov 28 16:03:24 2019.
Dependencies resolved.
======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================= Package                                                             Arch                                                         Version                                                             Repository                                                  Size 
=======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================Installing:
 openvpn                                                             x86_64                                                       2.4.8-1.el8                                                         epel                                                       540 k 
Installing dependencies:
 pkcs11-helper                                                       x86_64                                                       1.22-7.el8                                                          epel                                                        64 k 

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================Install  2 Packages

Total download size: 604 k
Installed size: 1.4 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/2): pkcs11-helper-1.22-7.el8.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                             571 kB/s |  64 kB     00:00     
(2/2): openvpn-2.4.8-1.el8.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                                  4.3 MB/s | 540 kB     00:00     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Total                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  197 kB/s | 604 kB     00:03     
warning: /var/cache/dnf/epel-fafd94c310c51e1e/packages/openvpn-2.4.8-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 2f86d6a1: NOKEY
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                         1.6 MB/s | 1.6 kB     00:00     
Importing GPG key 0x2F86D6A1:
 Userid     : "Fedora EPEL (8) <epel@fedoraproject.org>"
 Fingerprint: 94E2 79EB 8D8F 25B2 1810 ADF1 21EA 45AB 2F86 D6A1
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-8
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Key imported successfully
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               1/1 
  Installing       : pkcs11-helper-1.22-7.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                               1/2 
  Running scriptlet: openvpn-2.4.8-1.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2/2 
  Installing       : openvpn-2.4.8-1.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2/2 
  Running scriptlet: openvpn-2.4.8-1.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2/2 
  Verifying        : openvpn-2.4.8-1.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1/2 
  Verifying        : pkcs11-helper-1.22-7.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                               2/2 

Installed:
  openvpn-2.4.8-1.el8.x86_64                                                                                                      pkcs11-helper-1.22-7.el8.x86_64

Complete!
```

If I then try to enable or start OpenVPN with `sudo systemctl enable openvpn.service` / `sudo systemctl enable openvpn@server.service` or `sudo systemctl start openvpn.service` / `sudo systemctl start openvpn@server.service` it fails to enable or start as below.

```sh
Failed to enable (or start) unit: Unit file openvpn.service does not exist.
```

If I run `systemctl | grep openvpn` nothing at all is returned for OpenVPN.

After installing OpenVPN through `apt` on Ubuntu, if I call `sudo systemctl status openvpn.service` regardless of whether I have yet provided a `server.conf` then `systemctl` gives me a status back, as below.

```sh
● openvpn.service - OpenVPN service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

This is *not* happening on Red Hat 8. So my question is how can I find out why despite installing OpenVPN through `dnf` and having `server.conf` and the certificates in place, when I try to manage the service with `systemctl` the OpenVPN unit doesn't seem to have actually been installed?

Within the `/usr/lib/systemd/system` directory the below units exist.

```sh
openvpn-client@.service
openvpn-server@.service
```

If I run `sudo systemctl status openvpn-server@server` then I do actually get something back, but I can't start it, because it immediately fails.

```sh
● openvpn-server@server.service - OpenVPN service for server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:openvpn(8)
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
```

I have searched for a solution to no avail, so I hope somebody can help!

Answer (score 2):

For lack of detailed error logs from the poster, I will provide my solution here.
Having had the same problem on an AWS RHEL 8.2 instance, I found a few configuration
details needed tweaking to get the service running.
These may differ across templates & tutorials/blogs being used.

#### Ensure `server.conf` is in the correct directory

Depending on the tutorial you are following, the location of the `server.conf` will differ (if they mention this detail at all!).

Having set up server on Ubuntu before, I would usually store them in `/etc/openvpn/`. However, apparently for RHEL 8, it should be in `/etc/openvpn/server`, i.e.:

```
cd /etc/openvpn
sudo mv server.conf server/
```

#### Create the log folder

I found that it was necessary to create the `/var/log/openvpn` folder:

```
cd /var/log
sudo mkdir openvpn
```

Once these commands were run, I found that the directory had been magically populated with the necessary files. I'm curiuos to see if anyone has the same results.

#### Change `nogroup` to `nobody`

In `server.conf`, change the line that read `group nogroup` to `group nobody`.
This may be how it is in your config already but, coming from an Ubuntu background, I found this to be the most head scratching issue.

### Finally - Starting the service

Since the OP has listed quite a few commands that he tried - and other posters suggested more - I'll give the commands that worked for me:

```
sudo systemctl enable openvpn-server@server.service
```

**Note:** Some source suggest using the `-f` flag to force it: `sudo systemctl -f enable openvpn-server@server.service`,  but I didn't find this necessary.

Then:

```
sudo systemctl start openvpn-server@server.service
```

And you're done!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the openvpn service is not yet enabled properly.Enable the openvpn service by using the below command

```
systemctl enable openvpn@vpnname.service
```

You can start the OpenVPN service manually by using the below command

```
systemctl start openvpn@vpnname.service
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back so quickly but I should clarify that even with the `server.conf` configuration and certificates in-place, I can't actually enable or start the service, because `systemctl` says the unit does not exist when I try: `Failed to enable unit: Unit file openvpn@vpnname.service does not exist.`...

Comment: Can you share me the blog you used to install this OpenVPN server

Comment: Use systemctl start openvpn@server.service

Comment: As mentioned `systemctl start openvpn@server.service` and `systemctl enable openvpn@server.service` return `Failed to start (or enable) openvpn@server.service: Unit openvpn@server.service not found.`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there no service created as `openvpn@server.service`. 
Once you install the packages have to create the config file, in these case the file needs to be server.conf.

For example:

```
$ sudo cp /usr/share/doc/openvpn-*/sample/sample-config-files/server.conf /etc/openvpn 
$ sudo nano /etc/openvpn/server.conf
```

Once you configure correctly the server.conf you can use systemctl commands.

Try to use [these guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7). It's from Centos7 but it seems it's compatible with Red Had 8.